# How can I create an OSRM file from geojson data?

Tags: javascript, npm, osrm

I have a geojson datafile containing `highway=footway` paths, and I'd like to use OSRM to find routings between multiple points (i.e., not just the most efficient path from A to B, but something like the travelling salesman).

From the [OSRM documentation](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/nodejs/api.md), I see that to use custom data rather than data from OpenStreetMap I would need an OSRM file, which I can apparently make "by running the OSRM binaries [shipped] in node_modules/osrm/lib/binding/ and default profiles".

I find that very vague and I don't know how to proceed. The documentation linked above refers to the OSRM-backend documentation, but I didn't find anything related to creating OSRM files there. I got the `node_modules/osrm` directory through npm, but there's nothing in the `osrm/lib/binding` directory...

How can I proceed to use my data for OSRM routing? Or if there is an easier solution to what I'm trying to implement, what would it be?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create an osrm file by following this "pipeline":

1. Convert the geojson file to osm using [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) (or start with an osm file to begin with). You can do this by opening the geojson file and clicking on File > Save As... and then selcting OSM file format.
2. Add the version, timestamp and changeset tags with [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Download):

```bash
$ osmconvert64 intput_file.osm --fake-author -o=output_file.osm
```

3. Make the osm file into a binary file with [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Installation):

```bash
$ osmosis --rx input_file.osm --wb output_file.osm.pbf omitmetadata=true
```

4. Use the OSRM Docker container to create the osrm file. With Docker desktop installed:

```bash
$ docker run -t -v "absolute/path/to/data":/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/profile.lua /data/file_name.osm.pbf
$ docker run -t -v "absolute/path/to/data":/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-contract /data/file_name.osrm
```

### Notes:

- For the docker step, you must create a `data` directory and the absolute path to data should link to that directory.
- The file_name used must be the same for the `osrm-extract` input as for the `osrm-contract` output, as OSRM will make some other files using that name, which it will try to find in the contract step.